# Outlook fails to recognize custom UID in .ics file, creates new event (and new id)

Tags: outlook, icalendar, uid, rfc5545

What I am trying to do:
I have a need to send my clients `.ics` files that will populate their Outlook calendars as soon as they download and double click (and choose to populate their Outlook calendar).

When I am testing locally, the iCalendar code below works fine if I set Outlook to work `offline` - a UID is generated `once` for each event, I can use the same file again and again and a new event will `not` be generated - as the UID is recognized by Outlook as already existing. (so I can rely on the UID to update, and cancel as well)

The issue is that when I work with an `online` Outlook, a random UID (112 characters long) is generated every time I use the file to populate the calendar - even for the same events - so a duplicate event is generated `every time!`
Example for an .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:12345
DTSTART:20190715T020222Z
DTEND:20190715T030222Z
DESCRIPTION:Some fake summary - first event
DTSTAMP:20190715T010222Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:this is the first event summary
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:67890
DTSTART:20190715T040222Z
DTEND:20190715T050222Z
DESCRIPTION:Some fake summary - second event
DTSTAMP:20190715T010222Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:this is the second event summary
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

If I generate an .ics file for the first event that was generated when Outlook is `online` (dragging and dropping out of the calendar) I see that Outlook has added a bunch of new fields:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook for Mac MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Pacific Time (US & Canada)
X-ENTOURAGE-CFTIMEZONE:US/Pacific
X-ENTOURAGE-TZID:1
BEGIN:STANDARD
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSECOND=0;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
DTSTART:20071104T020000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSECOND=0;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
DTSTART:20070311T020000
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:<a NEW 112 character id - NOT the one I added myself>
X-ENTOURAGE_UUID:81760164-FB2C-4421-B7AC-2E1791265F0A
X-MICROSOFT-EXCHANGE-ID:<base64, 140 character id>
X-MICROSOFT-EXCHANGE-CHANGEKEY:<base64, 32 character id>
DTSTAMP:20190715T023949Z
DTSTART;TZID="Pacific Time (US & Canada)":20190714T190200
DTEND;TZID="Pacific Time (US & Canada)":20190714T200200
LAST-MODIFIED:20190715T023949Z
SUMMARY:this is the first event summary
DESCRIPTION:Some fake summary - first event
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:<the real account owner email - my email>
SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

What I tried:

1. Modified: `METHOD:REQUEST`
2. Added `X-WR-RELCALID:some_unique_id` [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlookhttps://)
3. Sequence does not seem to help - it is only there to sort out if 2 UIDs are the same within the same file
4. I added `ORGANIZER;CN=Fable mail:MAILTO:fable.mail@example.com` to each event - it has the same issue as the UID, and is disregarded (my email is added as the organizer)
5. I added `ATTENDEE:MAILTO:somemail@email.com` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509045/google-calendar-ignoring-ics-uid-when-using-add-to-calendar-link), but it does not seem to make any difference

Is it because I am not using the [recommended standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7) for the UID? It seems like a suggestion to prevent collisions, nothing more.

Thank you!

Comment: Dis you ever solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not, I can't remember what I did at the time working at that company, but I hacked something around it

Answer (score 1):

The problem still persists on latest Outlook 2019 from Office 365.

Even Microsoft support suggests to add this as feature request to the outlook suggestion box. (see here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ics-file-does-not-update-event/38548f62-d9cd-4b85-8d3e-65217d4e8f50)

Others suggest to create an application which communicates with outlook and synchronizes the calendar entries by this way. But in my opinion this is a too heavy solution for such a small problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the .ics file to outlook live via the desktop browser, I have used edge mobile set as desktop for this, and select *add calendar* in the expanded left sidebar followed by *upload from file* in the following selection menu the UID replacement does not take place.

P.S. Entering the data via outlook mail replaced the UIDs even if they did comply to the official recommendations in the specification.